# Failed to import timezonefinder in python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

i got stuck in importing "timezonefinder" module recently, when i run this python code in jupyter notebook:

```
import timezonefinder
```

The following exception occured:

```
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\targets\base.py in get_constant_generic(self, builder, ty, val)
    498         try:
--> 499             impl = self._get_constants.find((ty,))
    500             return impl(self, builder, ty, val)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\targets\base.py in find(self, sig)
     49         if out is None:
---> 50             out = self._find(sig)
     51             self._cache[sig] = out

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\targets\base.py in _find(self, sig)
     58         else:
---> 59             raise NotImplementedError(self, sig)
     60 

NotImplementedError: (<numba.targets.base.OverloadSelector object at 0x0000020A10A2B0F0>, (readonly bytes(uint8, 1d, C),))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\errors.py in new_error_context(fmt_, *args, **kwargs)
    616     try:
--> 617         yield
    618     except NumbaError as e:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\lowering.py in lower_block(self, block)
    258                                    loc=self.loc, errcls_=defaulterrcls):
--> 259                 self.lower_inst(inst)
    260 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\lowering.py in lower_inst(self, inst)
    307             ty = self.typeof(inst.target.name)
--> 308             val = self.lower_assign(ty, inst)
    309             self.storevar(val, inst.target.name)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\lowering.py in lower_assign(self, ty, inst)
    448             res = self.context.get_constant_generic(self.builder, ty,
--> 449                                                     value.value)
    450             self.incref(ty, res)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\targets\base.py in get_constant_generic(self, builder, ty, val)
    501         except NotImplementedError:
--> 502             raise NotImplementedError("Cannot lower constant of type '%s'" % (ty,))
    503 

NotImplementedError: Cannot lower constant of type 'readonly bytes(uint8, 1d, C)'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

LoweringError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-34c219114d8a> in <module>()
----> 1 import timezonefinder

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\timezonefinder\__init__.py in <module>()
      1 from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
      2 
----> 3 from .timezonefinder import TimezoneFinder
      4 
      5 __version__ = '3.4.2'

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\timezonefinder\timezonefinder.py in <module>()
     20 try:
     21     import numba
---> 22     from .helpers_numba import coord2int, distance_to_polygon_exact, distance_to_polygon, inside_polygon, \
     23         all_the_same, rectify_coordinates, coord2shortcut, convert2coord_pairs, convert2coords
     24 except ImportError:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\timezonefinder\helpers_numba.py in <module>()
    307 
    308 # @cc.export('rectify_coordinates', dtype_2float_tuple(f8, f8))
--> 309 @njit(dtype_2float_tuple(f8, f8), cache=True)
    310 def rectify_coordinates(lng, lat):
    311     if lng > 180.0 or lng < -180.0 or lat > 90.0 or lat < -90.0:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\decorators.py in wrapper(func)
    181             with typeinfer.register_dispatcher(disp):
    182                 for sig in sigs:
--> 183                     disp.compile(sig)
    184                 disp.disable_compile()
    185         return disp

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler_lock.py in _acquire_compile_lock(*args, **kwargs)
     30         def _acquire_compile_lock(*args, **kwargs):
     31             with self:
---> 32                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
     33         return _acquire_compile_lock
     34 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\dispatcher.py in compile(self, sig)
    653 
    654             self._cache_misses[sig] += 1
--> 655             cres = self._compiler.compile(args, return_type)
    656             self.add_overload(cres)
    657             self._cache.save_overload(sig, cres)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\dispatcher.py in compile(self, args, return_type)
     80                                       args=args, return_type=return_type,
     81                                       flags=flags, locals=self.locals,
---> 82                                       pipeline_class=self.pipeline_class)
     83         # Check typing error if object mode is used
     84         if cres.typing_error is not None and not flags.enable_pyobject:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py in compile_extra(typingctx, targetctx, func, args, return_type, flags, locals, library, pipeline_class)
    924     pipeline = pipeline_class(typingctx, targetctx, library,
    925                               args, return_type, flags, locals)
--> 926     return pipeline.compile_extra(func)
    927 
    928 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py in compile_extra(self, func)
    372         self.lifted = ()
    373         self.lifted_from = None
--> 374         return self._compile_bytecode()
    375 
    376     def compile_ir(self, func_ir, lifted=(), lifted_from=None):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py in _compile_bytecode(self)
    855         """
    856         assert self.func_ir is None
--> 857         return self._compile_core()
    858 
    859     def _compile_ir(self):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py in _compile_core(self)
    842         self.define_pipelines(pm)
    843         pm.finalize()
--> 844         res = pm.run(self.status)
    845         if res is not None:
    846             # Early pipeline completion

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler_lock.py in _acquire_compile_lock(*args, **kwargs)
     30         def _acquire_compile_lock(*args, **kwargs):
     31             with self:
---> 32                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
     33         return _acquire_compile_lock
     34 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py in run(self, status)
    253                     # No more fallback pipelines?
    254                     if is_final_pipeline:
--> 255                         raise patched_exception
    256                     # Go to next fallback pipeline
    257                     else:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py in run(self, status)
    244                 try:
    245                     event(stage_name)
--> 246                     stage()
    247                 except _EarlyPipelineCompletion as e:
    248                     return e.result

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py in stage_nopython_backend(self)
    715         """
    716         lowerfn = self.backend_nopython_mode
--> 717         self._backend(lowerfn, objectmode=False)
    718 
    719     def stage_compile_interp_mode(self):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py in _backend(self, lowerfn, objectmode)
    664             self.library.enable_object_caching()
    665 
--> 666         lowered = lowerfn()
    667         signature = typing.signature(self.return_type, *self.args)
    668         self.cr = compile_result(

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py in backend_nopython_mode(self)
    651                 self.calltypes,
    652                 self.flags,
--> 653                 self.metadata)
    654 
    655     def _backend(self, lowerfn, objectmode):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py in native_lowering_stage(targetctx, library, interp, typemap, restype, calltypes, flags, metadata)
   1046         lower = lowering.Lower(targetctx, library, fndesc, interp,
   1047                                metadata=metadata)
-> 1048         lower.lower()
   1049         if not flags.no_cpython_wrapper:
   1050             lower.create_cpython_wrapper(flags.release_gil)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\lowering.py in lower(self)
    176         if self.generator_info is None:
    177             self.genlower = None
--> 178             self.lower_normal_function(self.fndesc)
    179         else:
    180             self.genlower = self.GeneratorLower(self)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\lowering.py in lower_normal_function(self, fndesc)
    217         # Init argument values
    218         self.extract_function_arguments()
--> 219         entry_block_tail = self.lower_function_body()
    220 
    221         # Close tail of entry block

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\lowering.py in lower_function_body(self)
    242             bb = self.blkmap[offset]
    243             self.builder.position_at_end(bb)
--> 244             self.lower_block(block)
    245 
    246         self.post_lower()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\lowering.py in lower_block(self, block)
    257             with new_error_context('lowering "{inst}" at {loc}', inst=inst,
    258                                    loc=self.loc, errcls_=defaulterrcls):
--> 259                 self.lower_inst(inst)
    260 
    261     def create_cpython_wrapper(self, release_gil=False):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py in __exit__(self, type, value, traceback)
    128                 value = type()
    129             try:
--> 130                 self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
    131             except StopIteration as exc:
    132                 # Suppress StopIteration *unless* it's the same exception that

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\errors.py in new_error_context(fmt_, *args, **kwargs)
    623         from numba import config
    624         tb = sys.exc_info()[2] if config.FULL_TRACEBACKS else None
--> 625         six.reraise(type(newerr), newerr, tb)
    626 
    627 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\six.py in reraise(tp, value, tb)
    657         if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
    658             raise value.with_traceback(tb)
--> 659         raise value
    660 
    661 else:

LoweringError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython mode backend)
Cannot lower constant of type 'readonly bytes(uint8, 1d, C)'

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\timezonefinder\helpers_numba.py", line 312:
def rectify_coordinates(lng, lat):
    <source elided>
    if lng > 180.0 or lng < -180.0 or lat > 90.0 or lat < -90.0:
        raise ValueError(b'The coordinates should be given in degrees. They are out ouf bounds.')
        ^

[1] During: lowering "$const32.2 = const(bytes, b'The coordinates should be given in degrees. They are out ouf bounds.')" at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\timezonefinder\helpers_numba.py (312)
```

Solutions i've tried up to now:

1. reinstall "numba" module, not work;
2. uninstall "numba" module directly, problem solved but the execution speed of timezonefiner got slower siginificantly;

So, can anyone know how to figure out this problem? Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's because timezonefinder is not suported by numba. You can check [supported python features](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/pysupported.html).

The information about [timezonefinder](https://timezonefinder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) is not clear about that so, the reference for numba supported features is [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/pysupported.html#third-party-modules).

Take a look at [overloading with numba](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/extending/overloading-guide.html) for overloading (for using "third-party library that you do not control and you wish to provide Numba compatible implementations for specific functions from that library")

Comment: But seems the "timezonefinder" can run well in my colleagues' PC.